How is it possible that I'm locking a mutex multiple times, if mutex shall be possible to be locked only once?
I'm trying to understand c++ semaphore and mutex, and I found out that I'm locking 1 mutex several times, or at least my debugging messages are showing that is the case.
Even though we have only 1 mutex in semaphore, I'm aquiring it for more than 1 thread.
I understand that semaphore is supposed to allow the access by mutltiple threads (limited by the counter), but internally semaphore is made of mutex that can have value 0 or 1, taken or not taken.
In my opinion it shall be not possible that 2 threads will lock the mutex 1 after another, but I can see that in the log file
/**
 * Connecting cell phones to a charger
 */
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdio>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

unsigned int data_race = 0;

class Semaphore {
public:
    Semaphore(unsigned long init_count) {
        count_ = init_count;
    }

    void acquire(int id) { // decrement the internal counter
        printf("%d wants to aquire.\n", id);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m_);
        printf("%d aquired mutex in aquire\n", id);
        while (!count_) {
            printf("%d is waiting for lock\n", id);
            cv_.wait(lck);
        }
        printf("%d is about to decrease count\n", id);
        count_--;
    }

    void release(int id) { // increment the internal counter
        printf("%d is about to relase \n", id);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m_);
        printf("%d acuired mutex in release\n", id);
        count_++;
        lck.unlock();
       cv_.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    unsigned long count_;
};

Semaphore charger(2);

void cell_phone(int id) {
    charger.acquire(id);
    printf("Phone %d is charging...\n", id);
    srand(id); // charge for "random" amount between 1-3 seconds
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 2000 + 1000));
    printf("Phone %d is DONE charging!\n", id);
    charger.release(id);
}

int main() {
    std::thread phones[6];
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        phones[i] = std::thread(cell_phone, i);
    }
    for (auto& p : phones) {
        p.join();
    }
}

It's compiled with c++17, I thought that only 1 mutex will be aquired at once in this implemenation.
The result:
PS C:\HHardDrive\embedded C\output> & .\'Semaphore_CriticalSection2.exe'
0 wants to aquire.
0 aquired mutex in aquire    //->Mutex locked first time
0 is about to decrease count
Phone 0 is charging...      
4 wants to aquire.
4 aquired mutex in aquire    //->Mutex locked second time
4 is about to decrease count
Phone 4 is charging...      
3 wants to aquire.
3 aquired mutex in aquire   
3 is waiting for lock       
2 wants to aquire.
2 aquired mutex in aquire   
2 is waiting for lock       
5 wants to aquire.
5 aquired mutex in aquire
1 wants to aquire.
5 is waiting for lock
1 aquired mutex in aquire
1 is waiting for lock
Phone 0 is DONE charging!
0 is about to relase 
0 acuired mutex in release
Phone 4 is DONE charging!
3 is about to decrease count
4 is about to relase
4 acuired mutex in release
Phone 3 is charging...
2 is about to decrease count
Phone 2 is charging...
Phone 2 is DONE charging!
2 is about to relase 
Phone 3 is DONE charging!
2 acuired mutex in release
3 is about to relase
5 is about to decrease count
Phone 5 is charging...
3 acuired mutex in release
1 is about to decrease count
Phone 1 is charging...
Phone 1 is DONE charging!
Phone 5 is DONE charging!
1 is about to relase
5 is about to relase 
1 acuired mutex in release
5 acuired mutex in release


When you wait on a condition variable the mutex is released during the time the thread sleeps (and is re-acquired for checking the condition).

A side note: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?.

Also : NEVER wait on a condition variable without a predicate! Condition variables can have what is called "spurious wakeups" (something C++ cannot help, it is an OS thing). S

@PepijnKramer never say never. calling wait from a while loop (as they do here) is exactly equivalent to using a predicate

Please post your program's output as text in a code block, not as an image.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

I don't understand the question.  Which two threads do you believe acquired the output at the same time, and why do you think your program's output indicates this?  Please explain in more detail, not just by drawing arrows on the output.

Acquired the mutex*

@AlanBirtles Fair enough :) Missed the while loop logic

@NateEldredge I've edited it and paster the output as text, thanks. I tried to explain it a bit more. Do you have any specific question?

@wohlstad thank you so much for such a quick response! I'm not sure if I would agree with that, because if that would be the case then I would see the information " printf("%d is waiting for lock\n", id);" just before locking 2nd lock. It's not the case in the output. There are only 3 ways to unlock: 1) wait 2) unlock 3) RAII because it's unique lock. Right now I'm thinking that it makes sense that it's acually beacause of RAII for Unique lock. What do you think?

@wohlstad without #include <bits/stdc++.h> I get a compiler error: c:\HHardDrive\embedded C\Semaphore_CriticalSection2.cpp:52:5: error: 'srand' was not declared in this scope
52 |     srand(id); // charge for "random" amount between 1-3 seconds
|     ^~~~~
c:\HHardDrive\embedded C\Semaphore_CriticalSection2.cpp:53:59: error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope
53 |     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 2000 + 1000));

The message "waiting for lock" should rather be "waiting for charger port". The "lock" it refers to is not the lock on the mutex but rather that someone increments the semaphore counter. I honestly can't tell any place something is wrong in your output, it even shows how 1 seems to be blocked (or scheduled out by chance) while trying to lock the mutex, so that part seems to work. Can you [edit] your question to clarify where exactly you think multple threads simultaneously have a lock on the mutex?

srand(id); // charge for "random" amount between 1-3 seconds the code isn't really good and the comment doesn't make it any better, btw. However, at least you create deterministic behaviour here for subsequent runs. At least if you're lucky. If it's not thread-safe (which it isn't guaranteed to), you get undefined behaviour.

@DanielDobiński to use rand() and srand(), you need #include <stdlib.h> or #include <cstdlib>. However, they are old and troublesome, you are better off using the modern random number generators in <random> instead.

Two hints: First, if you want to discuss about locking mutexes only, please make your example more simple, without srand, just two concurrent threads, clear timings etc. Second, add timestamps to your debug messages, because you shouldn't rely on the sequence of stdout, only.

Thread 0 unlocked the mutex in acquire() in the destructor of std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck, which executed upon exiting the block where it was defined.  This happened just before acquire returned, and shortly after the message "0 is about to decrease count" was printed.  So thread 0 had indeed unlocked the lock before thread 4 locked it.
This RAII pattern is the whole point of unique_lock; it locks the mutex at the point where the unique_lock is defined (i.e. where its constructor runs), holds the lock from there until the unique_lock goes out of scope (normally the end of the enclosing block), and then unlocks it in the destructor.
